# Drupal 7 get node reference custom field in path auto pattern

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In drupal I have 2 content type "events" and "news". news content type have a node reference field "field_associated_event" to select events from events content type. events have also 2 another field text field "field_url_one" and "field_url_two"

In path auto pattern for events

[node:field_url_one]/[node:field_url_two]/events

For news url I want to get this but it's not working

[node:field_url_one]/[node:field_url_two]/news/{news alias} - not working

at give result in url only : news/{news alias}

I have using entity, entity reference module but not get token to reference fields. It get only event title if I used

[node:field_associated_event]/news/{news alias}

It works fine and get event title in url.

How to get event fields in url for news page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `Entity tokens` module (comes with `Entity` module). Then you will be able to use `[node:field-associated-event:field_url_one]` and `[node:field-associated-event:field_url_two]` tokens in your path patterns.

Note using hyphen instead of underline (i.e. correct is `[node:field-associated-event]`, NOT `[node:field_associated_event]`).

Comment: For those who cannot find the `Entity tokens` module, please note that it is a submodule of [Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity).

Comment: Both are already installed and enabled. Not found [node:field-associated-event:field_url_one]. It giving error "The Pattern for all News Post paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field-associated-event:field_url_one]"

Comment: Try to open Help/Token and search for requred tokens under Node list item.

Comment: Yes checked same place. one thing I found issue with multi select checkboxs. I have created another field with radio button, [node:field-associated-event:field_url_two] working and get result. For multi select it giving option Nodes with delta 1, Nodes with delta 2, Nodes with delta 3...how we can handle url for multi-select reference field ?